# Arrange multiple scrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, scroll

[image]

I want to arrange three `scrollView` in one view.

1. Left `scrollView` -> Scroll up/down at same time center `scrollView` must be scroll up/down.
2. Top `scrollView` -> Scroll left/right at same time center `scrollView` must be scroll up/down.

Please don't forgot about sequence.

1. Top `scrollView` is upper `scrollView`.
2. Left `scrollView` is middel `scrollView`.
3. center `scrollView` is lower `scrollView`.

Please if you have any other solution then tell me.

Comment: Are you using xib or ?

Comment: @Madhumitha : yes, i am using .xib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it....

```
- (void)matchScrollView:(UIScrollView *)first toScrollView:(UIScrollView *)second
{
    CGPoint offset = first.contentOffset;
    offset.y = second.contentOffset.y;
    [first setContentOffset:offset];
}

- (void)matchScrollView1:(UIScrollView *)first toScrollView:(UIScrollView *)second
{
    CGPoint offset = first.contentOffset;
    offset.x = second.contentOffset.x;
    [first setContentOffset:offset];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if([scrollView isEqual:stageScrollView])
    {
        [self matchScrollView:artistScrollView toScrollView:stageScrollView];
    }
    else
    {
        [self matchScrollView:stageScrollView toScrollView:artistScrollView];
    }

    if([scrollView isEqual:hourScrollView])
    {
        [self matchScrollView1:artistScrollView toScrollView:hourScrollView];
    }
    else
    {
        [self matchScrollView1:hourScrollView toScrollView:artistScrollView];
    }
}
```

hourScrollView -> Top scrollView.
stageScrollView -> Middel scrollView.
artistScrollView -> Bottom scrollView.

Don't forgot to set delegate in .h file and in .xib file.

Hope i helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using two Class methods of `UIScrollView` :

**1)** `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` :

Get the Content Offset in this method using : `CGPoint offset = [yourScrollViewA contentOffset];`

**2)** `- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated`

Set the other control here.

```
if ( scrollView == yourScrollViewA ) // change offset of B
else // change offset of A
```

For more help go through [UIScrollView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html).

GoodLuck !!!